# Running "sudo su" in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, sudo

I try to run inital playbook on remote host, i.e. set SSH public key. Problem is, without SSH I cannot connect. I tried stuff like this, but it does not work.

```
- hosts: remote_host
  become: yes
  become_user: mongod
  become_method: sudo
  become_exe: "sudo su - "

  tasks:

  - name: Add public ssh keys
    lineinfile:
      path: /home/mongod/.ssh/authorized_keys
      owner: mongod
      group: mongod
      mode: '0600' 
      state: present 
      line: "{{ item }}"
    loop:
      - "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2E...= domscheit@ansible_host"
```

Note, `sudo su - mongod` is the **only** command I can run as user `domscheit`. I have no password for user `mongod`, thus I cannot use it directly for connection. Above playbook returns error like `FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}`

Actually I found a solution:

```
- hosts: remote_host
  tasks:

  - name: Add public ssh-key to authorized_keys
    shell: |
      sudo su - mongod <<< "mkdir --mode=700 /home/mongod/.ssh"
      sudo su - mongod <<< "echo ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza...= domscheit@ansible_host >> /home/mongod/.ssh/authorized_keys"
      sudo su - mongod <<< "chmod 600 /home/mongod/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
```

It is working, however there should be a better solution. It creates `[WARNING]: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running sudo`

Once the public ssh-key is set, I can continue with my actual playbooks using `--user mongod`.

Comment: I'm not sure which part that doesn't work, but have you tried the official support for authorized_keys? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/authorized_key_module.html

Comment: @chelmertz It is not about the task itself. I cannot connect as user `mongod` because I don't have the password and public ssh-key is not added yet. I can connect only as user `domscheit` (and no root of course, otherwise it would be simple) but this user cannot modify the mongod home. Thus I have to run `sudo su - mongod` in between, that's what I try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

As @chelmertz mentioned you don't need (or even you shouldn't) adding ssh key by echoing it via cmd or whatever. There is `authorized_key` module in ansible exactly for this. It will take care about proper privileges and what not so your key will not only be added but also working as expected.

Run playbook with task adding ssh key for user `mongod` using just `become: yes`:

```
- hosts: remote_host
  become: yes
  tasks:

    - name: Set authorized key taken from file
      authorized_key:
      user: mongod
      state: present
      key: "{{ lookup('file', '/path/to/your/pub/key/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

Comment: Get error: `FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}` respectively `UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}`, see my comment above.